# I want to stop data importing from other textbox too when user age is under 24

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a listbox for customer name textbox, one listbox for nationality textbox and one DateTimePicker for date of birth listbox. One submit button for everthing to input. I want want to make sure if Customer age is < 24 then nothing will import in listboxs. I manage to show error for the date of birth if the customer is under 24 but it still imports everything from textbox.

```vb
Private Sub txtbirth_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbirth.ValueChanged
    Dim thisYear As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year
    Dim yourYear As Integer = txtbirth.Value.Year
    If thisYear - yourYear < 24 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer must be 24 and over")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    lstFname.Items.Add(txtForename.Text)
    txtForename.Text = ""
    lstSname.Items.Add(txtSurname.Text)
    txtSurname.Text = ""
    lstBirth.Items.Add(txtBirth.Text)
    txtBirth.Text = ""
    lstNationality.Items.Add(txtNationality.Text)
    txtNationality.Text = ""
    lstLicence.Items.Add(txtLicence.Text)
    txtLicence.Text = ""
    Pancustomer.Hide()
    Pancusbar.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: What type is `txtbirth`?

Comment: Also the math does not determine if someone is 24. It just determines if there are 24 years between their birth year and today's date. For example if the birthday is Dec 1997 and today is Nov 2021, then they are not quite 24 but your system will determine they are.

Comment: I named DateTimePicker as txtbirth

Comment: Ok. Well that's confusing. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: `it still imports everything from textbox` what does this mean?

Comment: so I have other textboxes for customer name and nationality so when customer is not aged 24 or over I don't want anything to go into listboxes.

Comment: this is the other bite of code for Submit button   `'Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        lstFname.Items.Add(txtForename.Text)
        txtForename.Text = ""

        lstSname.Items.Add(txtSurname.Text)
        txtSurname.Text = ""

        lstBirth.Items.Add(txtBirth.Text)
        txtBirth.Text = ""

        lstNationality.Items.Add(txtNationality.Text)
        txtNationality.Text = ""

        lstLicence.Items.Add(txtLicence.Text)
        txtLicence.Text = ""

        Pancustomer.Hide()
        Pancusbar.Hide()`

Comment: Right, so it looks like you just need to surround the code inside the button with an age check, like in my answer. It's impossible to format multi-line code in comments, don't bother :)

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

The DateTimePicker.ValueChanged event is very eager to fire every time you touch the calendar, so I guess that's the issue. Why not just check the age when you click the button?

```vb
Private minAge As Integer = 24
Private birthday As DateTime

' txtbirth is a DateTimePicker
Private Sub txtbirth_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbirth.ValueChanged
    birthday = txtbirth.Value
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If userIsOldEnough() Then
        lstFname.Items.Add(txtForename.Text)
        txtForename.Text = ""
        lstSname.Items.Add(txtSurname.Text)
        txtSurname.Text = ""
        lstBirth.Items.Add(txtBirth.Text)
        txtBirth.Text = ""
        lstNationality.Items.Add(txtNationality.Text)
        txtNationality.Text = ""
        lstLicence.Items.Add(txtLicence.Text)
        txtLicence.Text = ""
        Pancustomer.Hide()
        Pancusbar.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show($"Customer must be {minAge} and over")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function userIsOldEnough() As Boolean
    Return getAge(birthday) > minAge
End Function

Private Shared Function getAge(birthday As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim now = DateTime.Now
    Dim age = now.Year - birthday.Year
    If now < birthday.AddYears(age) Then age -= 1
    Return age
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped

Comment: @TahsinReza The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.